# ImageView is not visible

Tags: android, android-imageview, rotateanimation

I have two `ImageView` items in `FrameLayout`: *imageView1* and *imageView2*. *imageView1* is visible and *imageView2* is positioned out of screen when activity starts. Then I rotate `FrameLayout` on some user event using `RotateAnimation` so *imageView2* should become visible and *imageView1* should go out of screen. But *imageView2* still remains invisible. Does anyone know what's the reason?

The code is too large and complicated to show here. But as I have figured out the main problem in translating and rotating images using *setImageMatrix* function and special behavior of `FrameLayout` or `ImageView`, which crop image if it is out of their bounds.

Comment: and the layout xml file would be helpful too. LinearLayout is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly your situation, then you are mistaken. FrameLayout places it's children in stack, not side by side. So they aren't rendered out of screen, imageView2 is right behind imageView1. And to show it, you should bring it to front.

I would suggest you to look at ViewSwitcher/ViewAnimator layouts. I think they'll suit your needs.

Comment: You need to call showNext(), showPrevious() fro those layouts. I'll be much easier if you will provide your xml layout

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. I've just change height in `LayoutParams` of `FrameLayout` from "fill_parent" to exact height, which allows to keep all `ImageView`'s in `FrameLayout`.